# How to replace string with variable value in Tcl/Expect

Tags: unix, tcl, expect

I am trying to replace a specific string (`hostname`), inside a main string, with a variable value using the following command,

```
set newVar [string map {`hostname` $theHost} 'lsnrctl status listener_`hostname`']
```

However, instead of replacing `hostname` with the variable value, it replaces it using the variable identifier, i.e. "$theHost".

The newVar reads like this,

```
lsnrctl status listener_$theHost
```

I want it to be this,

```
lsnrctl status listener_theHostName
```

where "theHostName" is the value of the variable "$theHost".

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build the replace list with the `list`command:

```
set newVar [string map [list `hostname` $theHost] "lsnrctl status listener_`hostname`"
```

or you could just use

```
set newVar "lsnrctl status listener_${theHost}"
```

`'` has no special meaning in Tcl, so your snippet will throw an error.
use `"` if you want command, variable  and backslash substitution, `{` if you don't want this. (`\` before the end of a line will be still substituted).

So using `` {`hostname` $theHost} `` will be substituted to `` `hostname` $theHost ``, not the thing you want. So better build a list with `list`, `` "`hostname` $theHost" `` might work if $theHost is a valid list element (does not contain spaces, etc), but will fail if the value of `$theHost` is `foo bar` (`string map` will throw an error)

Comment: Awesome! This worked for me (the first option). You just saved my life :D

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do

```
set newVar 'lsnrctl status listener_'
append newVar $theHost
```

Comment: I'm planning to make this part also as a variable: lsnrctl status listener_ ... Though your suggestion seems really neat, I dont think I could use it in that situation. Any suggestions?